# Как удалить элемент массива?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

Предположим есть массив - array[1000].
Нужно удалить элемент 400 и при этом сдвинуть массив с 401 на 400, 402 на 401 и т.д.
Как это сделать одной командой без циклов?

Comment: Алгоритм `std::move`.

Comment: С массивами без циклов наверное никак, но можно использовать списки, там операция удаления дешёвая (`O(1)`). Только вот чтобы добраться до `i`-го элемента понадобится пройти от начала списка до `i`-го элемента. Ну и вообще подумайте в сторону использования другого контейнера.

Answer (score 3):

Например, старый добрый [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move):

```
std::move(array + 401, array + 1000, array + 400);
```

`array + 401`, `array + 1000` — это начало и конец (past-the-end) перемещаемых элементов, `array + 400` — адрес, начиная с которого они теперь будут размещаться. `std::move` позволяет сдвигать влево перекрывающиеся диапазоны; для сдвига вправо существует `std::move_backwards`.

Comment: Ну спрятали цикл за вызовом функции, но он же от этого не исчез?

Comment: Боюсь, он даже от std::memmove не исчезнет. :(

Comment: Можно, наверное, без циклов ^_^: `template<std::size_t i, std::size_t j> int *move(int *array) { if constexpr(i == j) return array; else return array[i - 1] = array[i], move<i + 1, j>(array); }`

Comment: После такой операции последный элемент массива будет иметь значение предыдущего...

Comment: И? Это чему-то противоречит?